# Pagination with Cassandra

Tags: node.js, pagination, cassandra

I am using cassandra with nodejs and I am trying to enable paginated request from the user's end.

For now, I limited the `fetchsize` of every request and users can pass in the `pageState` parameter in the request to fetch the next results as per the doc here: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/nodejs-driver/1.0/nodejs-driver/reference/paging.html

The problem with this method is that to get the results of the `n-th` page, a user has to sequentially make `n` queries to provide each time the correct `pageState` (assuming the `fetchSize` parameter is fixed.

Is there a way to paginate in such a way that users can directly access the `n-th` page?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi. I am struggling with the same problem at the moment. Did you find a solution or a workaround? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In Cassandra, it is not possible to access directly to the (n)th page of results without requesting (n-1)th page first.

You can read more about how pagination works in a distributed system like Cassandra in [this blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0).

Comment: Hi @jorgebg Is there a way to implement accessing directly the n-th page? We are trying to display the data in a Kendo Grid and want to enable paging to improve the user experience. Being able to navigate only to the previous and next pages seems quite restricting.